# After login to home page on go back again show login page in liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Iam facing problem in liferay 6.2. After login, when I click browser back button it was again showing login screen. But actual login happens(i.e session is maintaining). I dont want to see login page when clicking on back button. What should I do for this? Waiting for valuable response.

Comment: That function does not exist out of the box, if you are looking for something like that. But you can emulate it with a small JavaScript that you embed on your homepage. Just some hints: There are different ways to find out if the user has used the browsers _forward_ and _back_ buttons (some are using the `history` object, some the `location.hash`). And you can use an AJAX call to find out if the user is still logged in. I don't have an example at hand - maybe you will need to write your own endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in portal-ext.properties

browser.cache.disabled=true 
browser.cache.signed.in.disabled=true

Regards,
Aravinth

Comment: First of all,thanks for the response. I tried this. But when I click back button at first time, it shows web page is not available. Only when I click at second time, It showing previous page. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Hi Nasar,Did you try in different browsers.Are you getting any error in browser console?

Comment: Yes Aravinth, I tried in mozilla and firefox ,and I didnt find anything in browser console. The errors which I got in screen were Document expired and Confirm form resubmission in mozilla and chrome respectively. It shows while clicking browser back button after the action method called.